# How do i remove duplicates from this recursion code? Many 6-sided dice will be rolled and print only unique combinations that add up to a desired sum

Tags: c++

in the following code, I'm able to print all the dice combinations that add up to a desired sum. I'd like some help in tweaking the code to remove the duplicate entries.

```
void rep(int n, string ans, int currentSum, int targetSum)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        if(currentSum==targetSum)
            cout << "{" << ans << "}"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1 ; i<=6 ; i++)
        {
            if(n>1)
            {
                  rep(n-1, ans + to_string(i) + ", ", currentSum+i, targetSum);
            }
            else
            {
                rep(n-1, ans + to_string(i), currentSum+i, targetSum);
            }
        }
    }
}


void ManyDiceSum(int howManyDice, int targetSum)
{
    if(howManyDice>0)
        rep(howManyDice,"",0,targetSum);
}

int main()
{
    int howManyDice, targetSum;

    howManyDice=3;
    targetSum=7;

    ManyDiceSum(howManyDice, targetSum);

    return 0;
}
```

Output for 3 dice and target sum of 7 should be:

```
{1, 1, 5}
{1, 2, 4}
{1, 3, 3}
{2, 2, 3}
```

But, my code is displaying all combinations:

```
{1, 1, 5}
{1, 2, 4}
{1, 3, 3}
{1, 4, 2}
{1, 5, 1}
{2, 1, 4}
{2, 2, 3}
{2, 3, 2}
{2, 4, 1}
{3, 1, 3}
{3, 2, 2}
{3, 3, 1}
{4, 1, 2}
{4, 2, 1}
{5, 1, 1}
```

> Constraints are: **It has to use recursion** and use **only 1 loop** if
>   necessary.

Comment: Don't restart from 1, but from last added number, so you have only increasing sequences.

Comment: Btw, you might stop recursion as soon as you reach target: once you do `6 + 2`, no need to continue any other dice won't allow to have exactly 7.

Comment: What counts as a duplicate? None of the combinations in the sample output are quite the same.

Comment: @DanielH: {5,1,1} and {1,1,5} and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A exemplary solution based on @Jarod42's comment:

```
void rep(int n, std::string ans, int currentSum, int TargetSum, int startFrom) {
   if (n == 0) {
      if (currentSum == TargetSum)
         std::cout << "{" << ans << "}" << std::endl;
   } else 
      for (int i = startFrom; i <= 6; i++) 
         if (n > 1)
            rep(n-1, ans + to_string(i) + ", ", currentSum + i, TargetSum, i);
         else
            rep(n-1, ans + to_string(i), currentSum + i, TargetSum, i);
}

void ManyDiceSum(int howManyDice, int TargetSum) {
   if (howManyDice > 0)
      rep(howManyDice, "", 0, TargetSum, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need to pass both target and current sum to the function, only target is enough, and checking it first will speed up whole process significantly:

```
void rep( int n, int target, std::string ans = std::string(), int last = 1 )
{
    if( n == 0 ) {
        if( target == 0 )
            std::cout << "{" << ans << "}" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    const auto limit = std::min( 6, target );
    // or even following, but not sure this is quite right though
    //const auto limit = std::min( 6, target - n * last ); 
    for( int i = last ; i <= limit; ++i ) 
        rep(n-1, target - i, ans + to_string(i) + ( n > 1 ? ", " : "" ), i );
}

void ManyDiceSum( int howManyDice, int TargetSum ) 
{
   if (howManyDice > 0)
      rep( howManyDice, TargetSum );
}
```

and to avoid duplicates continue from the last number you started.